# jQuery call function after content get changed by .load() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very basic question concerning jQuery but I really don't know how to put it in a short sentence/ headwords to google for it. So first of all, I'm sorry if this might be a double post.

For my problem, I guess only those three files a relevant:

1. index.html
2. content.html
3. script.js

My **index.html** basically is just a file which keeps a navigation bar (build with Bootstrap v3.3.0).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom styles CSS -->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="content">Content</a></li>
                        ...
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- end navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!--end container -->
        </nav> <!-- end navbar -->


        <div class="container" id="mainContainer">

            <!-- Load by default from the Navigation with jQuery -->

        </div><!-- end container -->

        <footer>
            ....
        </footer>

        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Custom JS -->
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My **content.html** basically only displays a "button" now (Actually it displays much more, but for this example it only displays a "button")

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <a id="testButton" class="btn btn-success" href="#">This is a Test-Button</a>
</div>
```

My **script.js** basically only "changes" the content of the div-Element (`<div class="container" id="mainContainer">…</div>`).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav li a').click(function(e) {
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        var $content = $(this).attr('href');
        if (!$parent.hasClass('active')) {
            $parent.addClass('active');

            $('#mainContainer').hide().load($content + '.html').fadeIn('500');
            $('#mainFooter').hide().fadeIn('500');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#testButton').click(function(event){
        alert("Test, this Button works!");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Everything displayed here works pretty fine (I'm not sure if this is the way how you should use the navigation, but it works).  When I change the content by clicking on the *"Content-Item"* from the navigation, the **content.html** file gets displayed in the **div-element**. But when I click on the Button from the content.html (which was loaded before), **no alert** gets fired. I guess because the "javascript file", can't find a reverence when the Webpage loads the first time. When I enter the javscript code directly into the content.html file the button actually fires an alert (same happens when I only link the file `<script src="js/script.js"></script>`).

I really do not want to enter this single line of code (`<script src="js/script.js"></script>`) to every "content-file". So is there an easier way how to do that? Maybe I also need to change the way how I use the navigation.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Read: http://api.jquery.com/on/. `.load('$content + '.html')` you have an `'` extra. Such errors are clearly spottable in your developer console.  Also it's bad for SEO (if you care) to AJAX load a navigation.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry, my mistake. I copied those think together from my original project. This was just a "copy" mistake, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [event delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

It means you delegate `#testButton`'s `click` event to it's parent, even if the button is not yet exist in the dom, but when it is there, it's parent, in your situation, `#mainContainer` will be able to handle the button's event listener.

Like:

```
$('#mainContainer').on('click', '#testButton', function(event){
    alert("Test, this Button works!");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```